# How to differ between find criteria and initialize attributes in Rails 4 at find_or_initialize_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Until Rails 3 you could differ between find criteria and initialize attributes with find_or_initialize_by_name('Name', extra_attribute: 'value').
This only finds a record by name and criteria does not include extra attributes for initialization.

But in Rails 4 you can only pass one hash argument and complete hash is included in criteria, or am I wrong?

So how to differ between find criteria and initialize attributes in Rails 4 at find_or_initialize_by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Rails 4:

```
Model.where(name: 'Name').first_or_initialize(extra_attribute: 'value')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use [`create_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-create_with) to specify the new attributes:

```
new_obj = MyClass.create_with(extra_attribute: 'Value').find_or_initialize_by(name: 'Name')
```

Or you can pass a block to the find_or_initialize_by which gets called for initialized objects (and not found ones):

```
new_obj = MyClass.find_or_initialize_by(name: 'Name') do |obj|
  obj.extra_attribute = 'Value'
end
```